# Iframe obstructing the mousemove event from occuring

Tags: javascript, html, css

I attached an event on body. But a transparent Iframe appears on the body behind the popup. I want to call that mousemove event on the body, so that the popup disappears as soon as the mousemove occurs on the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had an issue with this before. What happens when you add an `iframe` to the `body` is that events that would normally be sent to the body like mousemove are being obstructed by that iframe.

I've fixed this by adding a absolute positioned `div` with 100% height and width over the iframe, whenever the popup opens. This `div` should have a higher z-index as the `iframe`.

Instead of listening to mousemove on the `body` you could then listen to the `div`. Remove the `div` whenever you are closing the popup.